# Is there a name for this aggregative design pattern?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I frequently find myself using the following pattern when I want to avoid using large switch statements (please excuse the hackneyed 'animal' theme):

```
public enum AnimalType { Dog, Cat, Hamster }

public interface IAnimal
{
    AnimalType AnimalType { get; }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public AnimalType AnimalType { get { return AnimalType.Cat; } }
}

public class AnimalAggregator
{
    private readonly IDictionary<AnimalType, IAnimal> _animals;

    public AnimalAggregator(IEnumerable<IAnimal> animals)
    {
        _animals = animals.ToDictionary(a => a.AnimalType);
    }

    public IAnimal Get(AnimalType animalType)
    {
        IAnimal animal;
        return _animals.TryGetValue(animalType, out animal) ? animal : null;
    }
}
```

In the above example I would take a dependency on `AnimalAggregator` and allow an IoC container to wire up the injection of all `IAnimal`s. Then instead of writing out a large switch statement for retrieving the `IAnimal` associated with `AnimalType.Cat`, I just call `animalAggregator.Get(AnimalType.Cat)`.

I have used this pattern (and variations thereof) many times in my projects but never known what to call it - I tend to go with "aggregator" but I'm not sure that's accurate. I have never seen it outside of my own code though.

Does it have a name?

Comment: Why not just use an abstract factory pattern?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Are you creating one instance for every animal type and then throw away all of them but the desired one just to avoid switching on the animal type?

Comment: @AlexG:  Can't comment on the name, but you don't need the ternary operator on your `Get` method. It will automatically assign the default value for `IAnimal` to `animal`. So your code can literally be: `IAnimal animal; _animals.TryGetValue(animalType, out animal); return animal;`

Comment: @DanielBrückner it tends to be for when I have many classes implementing the same interface and I want to dynamically choose between them. I suppose you could compare it to an abstract factory but it is not actually creating objects, just routing requests to the desired instance.

Comment: To explain further - It is borne of adherence to the Open-Closed Principle. When I need to add a new `Animal` to my program, the `AnimalAggregator` remains untouched, because the new `Animal` is injected through the constructor and identified by a new `AnimalType`

Comment: @AlexG Okay, then dispatcher is probably a better name than aggregator, it just happens to do the dispatching by first collecting all the instances in a collection, so this is an implementation detail.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I'll term it a Dispatcher from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

This feels to me like it should be an abstract factory pattern:

> Provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent
>   objects without specifying their concrete classes.

[image: Abstract pattern diagram]

You will then have an AnimalFactory with different GetMethods for each animal type.
I guess you could have a generic get method but this defeats the purpose of the abstract factory. Since you are in any way limited by the enum why not have a method per type.

For more info see http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a variation of the abstract factory pattern.  The only thing left to do is make `AnimalAggregator` extend an `IAnimalFactory` interface and change client code to take a dependency on `IAnimalFactory` instead of `AnimalAggregator`.

```
public inteface IAnimalFactory
{
    IAnimal Get(AnimalType t);
}
```

Comment: The generic get defeats the purpose of the abstract factory.

Comment: "The generic get defeats the purpose of the abstract factory" - no, that *is* the purpose of an abstract factory...